# Implementation of a "running hash" on constrained devices

Tags: protocol-design, implementation

The following link documents a proposal for a TLS-like alternative for constrained devices.
https://github.com/lake-wg/edhoc/blob/4f56898808989e449cc412a8b136674202a0ddce/draft-ietf-lake-edhoc.md#implementation-considerations-impl-cons

Unlike TLS1.3, the proposal does not make use of running hashes. Citing the proposal:

> The sequence of transcript hashes in EHDOC (TH_2, TH_3, TH_4) do not make use of a so-called running hash, this is a design choice as running hashes are often not supported on constrained platforms.

Why is it infeasible to implement a running hash in a constrained environment?

I can only think of an increased memory requirement to keep the state and input buffer, but it doesn't seem worse than hashing protocol messages separately in the context of such a protocol.

Comment: My guess (and this is a guess, hence this is a comment, not an answer) is that some low end platforms don't have the crypto API's available to do it; they have an API to do a full hash, but not a running one...

Comment: @poncho, thanks for the feedback. Seems like a reasonable explanation. Which makes me curious now as to why? Could it be the need for code/area efficiency? As in, more API would require more code etc? ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: My guess: the buy their cryptolibrary from a third party, and that library doesn't provide the necessary functionality.  I've seen this sort of thing too often in my day job...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote the cited text from EDHOC. I can confirm that this is purely an API problem. If your API does not support the Init, Update, Final pattern, you are forced to input the whole message as once. Some platforms force you to do that.

There is nothings hindering implementation of Init, Update, Final API on constrained devices. It actually makes a lot of sense there as the memory is contained and otherwise put a limit on how large messages that can be hashed.